# Is that fixed-size array? a[]

Tags: c, arrays, fixed-size-types

I am starting learning C programming.

`a[20]` and `a[]`

I understand `a[20]` is a **fixed-size** array but how about `a[]`?

Comment: What is the context/ usage?

Comment: If it's an argument, it's a pointer to the first element. If it's a definition and initialization (e.g., `int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };`) it just tells the compiler to count the number of elements and make the array exactly that size. If it's the last member of a `struct`, it's a flexible array member with flexible size allocated after the rest of the structure.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the proper context / usage, it's impossible to provide a direct answer, however, let me give example of some commonly used cases:

1. In a block scope, an array defined with the syntax like `a[]`,

   ```
   char a[] = "Some Name";
   ```

   is still a fixed-sized array. The size is obtained from the initializer, for example: the above array has a size of 10 (including the null terminator).
2. In other hand, in the case of a function argument, a syntax  like `a[]`,

   ```
   void func (int a[])
   ```

   is the same as

   ```
   void func (int *a)
   ```

   and it's not an array, it's a pointer.
3. If this syntax appears as the last element of a structure with more than one named member, this is called a flexible array member. It is an incomplete array type. For example:

   ```
   struct s { int n; double d[]; };
   ```

Comment: There's many other cases too like incomplete array types, flexible array members etc. The question can't be answered without context, like you asked for.

Comment: @Lundin  You're very right sir, I was trying to cover the commonly-used cases but let me expand to add some more. Meanwhile , I expect OP to get back with the context as I asked.